# Распаковка variadic templates

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть шаблонная функция, которая принимает на вход параметры `Args... args`, я бы хотела перегнать все аргументы в вектор строк `vector<string> arg` или можно к другой структуре, к которой удобно обращаться по индексу аргумента и которая содержит строковое представление каждого аргумента.

Как это лучше сделать ?

Comment: Это упаковка скорее. `::std::vector strs{::boost::lexical_cast< ::std::string >(args)...};`

Comment: если у вас все аргументы одного типа, то зачем использовать variadic template? Не проще ли использовать initialization list?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch у меня как раз аргументы разных типов, но нужно привести все к строкам

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Darya в таком случае решение выше работать не будет

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите на код ниже

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// для старых добрых сишных строк
std::string to_str(const char* c)
{
    return std::string(c);
}

// самый простой способ преобразовать число в строку
std::string to_str(double x) {
    return std::to_string(x);
}

// для целого просто вызываем to_string
std::string to_str(int x) {
    return std::to_string(x);
}

// покажем, что даже вектор можно будет обрабатывать
template <typename T>
std::string to_str(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::string s = "[ ";
    for (const T& el : v) {
        s += to_str(el) + " ";
    }
    s += ']';
    return s;
}
/* если у Вас будет какой то свой тип (своя чудо строка MyCoolString), то для нее нужно
просто определить функцию вида

std::string to_str(const MyCoolString& s)
{
   return "строковое представление";
}

И не обязательно в этом же файле, главное, что бы компилятор мог найти.
*/

//собственно магическая функция, которая делает всю магию
// для каждого аргумента она вызывает to_str, которая должна уметь преобразовать
// в строку.
template <typename...Args>
std::vector<std::string> to_vec(Args... params)
{
    return std::vector<std::string> {to_str(params)...};
}

// для удобства вывода
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::string>& s)
{
    for (const auto& s : s) {
        os << s << " ";
    }
    return os;
}

// пример вызова
int main()
{
    std::cout << to_vec(1,2, 1.2f, "a", std::vector<int>{1,2,3});
}
```

P.S. Можно было не городить город с to_str, а использовать везде std::to_string, но почему то для `const char*` в стандартной поставке там нет перегрузки, а также иногда хочется своих классов. Да, можно это все впихнуть вот так

```
namespace std {
  string to_string(const char* s) { return string(s); }
}
```

но засорение std - не лучшая идея.